# mysql Case statement not working in cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor, case

The case statement in the cursor does not work, however the select sql by itself works fine. Please advice whats the issue

```
 /* cursor for summed txns fee amounts of merchants */
  DECLARE sumCursor CURSOR FOR
  (
      SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, SUM(IF(feeTxn.isCredit='t', feeTxn.amt, -feeTxn.amt)) amt, MAX(feeTxn.feeTxnId) maxId, MIN(feeTxn.feeTxnId) minId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
      FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
      LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
      JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
      JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
      LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
      WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
      AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
      AND CASE
                WHEN includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) THEN feeTxn.txnDate <= dTxnDate
                ELSE feeTxn.txnDate < dTxnDate 
          END
      GROUP BY feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType
  );
```

Comment: Your query will be very very very slow...

Answer (score 0):

Unusual use of a CASE. Could you do without it, something like this:-

```
DECLARE sumCursor CURSOR FOR
(
    SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, SUM(IF(feeTxn.isCredit='t', feeTxn.amt, -feeTxn.amt)) amt, MAX(feeTxn.feeTxnId) maxId, MIN(feeTxn.feeTxnId) minId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
    FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
    LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
    JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
    JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
    LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
    WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
    AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
    AND ((includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) AND feeTxn.txnDate <= dTxnDate)
    OR feeTxn.txnDate < dTxnDate )
    GROUP BY feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType
);
```

Without seeing the data I am not sure if the following will help, but given your use of functions for small amounts of the data and effectively ORing of the data it might help MySQL to use indexes more effectively for performance if you split the query up into several queries unioned together. Something like this:-

```
SELECT toParticipantId, cardType, SUM(amt) AS amt, MAX(feeTxnId) AS maxId, MIN(feeTxnId) AS minId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
FROM (
SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, feeTxn.amt AS amt, feeTxn.feeTxnId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
INNER JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
INNER JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
AND includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) 
AND feeTxn.txnDate = dTxnDate
AND feeTxn.isCredit = 't'
UNION
SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, feeTxn.amt AS amt, feeTxn.feeTxnId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
INNER JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
INNER JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
AND feeTxn.txnDate < dTxnDate 
AND feeTxn.isCredit = 't'
UNION
SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, -feeTxn.amt AS amt, feeTxn.feeTxnId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
INNER JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
INNER JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
AND includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) 
AND feeTxn.txnDate = dTxnDate
AND feeTxn.isCredit != 't'
UNION
SELECT feeTxn.toParticipantId, txn.cardType, -feeTxn.amt AS amt, feeTxn.feeTxnId, IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) as acquirerId
FROM mas_feeTxn feeTxn
INNER JOIN mas_merchantDetail md ON feeTxn.toParticipantId = md.participantId AND md.status = 'A'
INNER JOIN mas_achInfo achInfo on achInfo.participantId = md.participantId and achInfo.status = 'A' and achInfo.fundingBankAccountId is not null 
LEFT JOIN mas_txn txn ON feeTxn.txnId = txn.txnId AND feeTxn.toParticipantId = txn.merchantId
LEFT JOIN mas_bankDetail bd ON md.bankId = bd.participantId AND bd.status = 'A'
WHERE feeTxn.billedStatus = 'f'
AND IFNULL(md.acquirerId, bd.acquirerId) = dAcquirerId
AND feeTxn.txnDate < dTxnDate 
AND feeTxn.isCredit != 't'
} Sub1
GROUP BY toParticipantId, cardType
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am dealing huge data. The only reason I wanted to use the case was to determine if includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) returns true then add feeTxn.txnDate <= dTxnDate in the where clause otherwise add feeTxn.txnDate < dTxnDate.  I was thinking, may be select the data with feeTxn.txnDate <= dTxnDate which will include all records and then in the cursor call the same function includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling(feeTxn.toParticipantId) to determine whether the record needs to be included or not.  Do you think it will reduce performance?

Comment: The function call will probably be rather slow, and using a case like that (like an OR) will likely prevent it using indexes. The union example above will hopefully allow it to use the indexes. However what does it do in includeTodaysTxnsInFeeBilling? If it is just checking a table it might be quicker to just directly join to that table.